# Prevent error if txt/json file is not in the right format (corrupted) before reading it

Tags: c#, io

I have an app that reads and rights to a `txt` file in a `json` format. Everything is working fine except that from time to time the `txt/json` file for some reason becomes corrupted and the app crashes when trying to read it.

Here is the code...

### User Class

```
    public class User
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

### usersFile.txt (json)

```
    [{"UserName":"someUserName"}]
```

### Reading Class

```
    public static string myUsersFolder = @"c:\myUsersFilder";
    string usersFile = Path.Combine(myUsersFolder, "usersFile.txt");    

    public void readUsersFromFile()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(usersFile))
                throw new FileNotFoundException();// throws an exception if the file is not found

                string jsonContent = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(myUsersFolder, usersFile));
                List<User> users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(jsonContent);

                foreach (var u in users)
                {
                    User user = new User();
                    user.UserName = u.UserName;
                    UsersObservableCollection.Add(user);
                }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException f)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Couldn't read users from file: " + f.Message);
        }
    }
```

### Error

> > 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'MyProgramName.ViewModel.ViewModelLocator' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.'

The issue is that if at some point the file `usersFile.txt` becomes corrupted, where the format is not right, for instance missing a `}` curly bracket, the app crashes.

```
[{"UserName":"someUserName"] // missing a curly bracket, app crashes
```

#### How can I prevent the app from crashing if the file is in the wrong format?

Comment: I'd consider adding another catch based on the type of exception that is being thrown and causing the crash.  You should then be able to handle the corupt file in there as you wish

Comment: @CF5 Adding another try-catch inside the `if (!File.Exists(usersFile))` right after the` throw new FileNotFoundException();` prevented the app from crashing if the file is corrupted but now the issue is that it for some reason deletes the file and recreates it every time it reads it, even if the file is in the right format. Thanks.

Comment: Got it, the file gets recreated because I'm writing to the file after reading it by calling `File.WriteAllText();` which recreates the file every time it is called, makes sense now. Documentation for `File.WriteAllText()` states the following:  **Creates a new file, writes the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten**. Thank  you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the .NET JSON serializer (`System.Text.Json`). The .NET JSON library has a modern async API ([How to serialize and deserialize (marshal and unmarshal) JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0).

The original exception you are experiencing is the result of the failed deserialization. You *could* (but shouldn't) wrap the deserialization part alone into a try-catch block. Also don't explicitly throw an exception (`FileNotFoundException`) just to catch it (even in the same context). Rather show the error message directly (or log it).

Exceptions are very expensive. You would always try to avoid them. Checking if the file exists successfully avoids the `FileNotFoundException`. Job done.

For this sake, the correct approach would be to validate the JSON *before* you  try to deserialize it: avoid the exception instead of handling it.

The following example shows a fixed version of your code. It also incorporates JSON validation to avoid any malformed input related exceptions.

The example also uses the `StreamReader` to read from the file asynchronously. this helps to avoid freezing your application during file handling. Generally use async APIs where possible.

```cs
public async Task readUsersFromFileAsync()
{
  if (!File.Exists(usersFile))
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Couldn't read users from file: " + f.Message);
  }

  using var fileReader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(myUsersFolder, usersFile));
  string jsonContent = await fileReader.ReadToEndAsync();

  if (!await TryValidateJsonInputAsync(jsonContent, out IList<string> errorMessages))
  {
    foreach (string errorMessage in errorMessages)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
    }

    return;
  }

  List<User> users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(jsonContent);
  foreach (var u in users)
  {
    User user = new User();
    user.UserName = u.UserName;
    UsersObservableCollection.Add(user);
  }
}

private Task<bool> TryValidateJsonInputAsync(string jsonContentToValidate, out IList<string> messages)
{
  var jsonSchemaText = new StreamReader("json_schema.txt"); 
  JSchema jsonSchema = JSchema.Parse(jsonSchemaText);
  JObject jsonToValidate = JObject.Parse(jsonContentToValidate);

  return jsonToValidate.IsValid(jsonSchema, out messages);
}
```

The example JSON schema used in the example (*json_schema.txt* file).

```json
{
  'description': 'A person',
  'type': 'object',
  'properties': {
    'name': {'type': 'string'},
    'hobbies': {
      'type': 'array',
      'items': {'type': 'string'}
    }
  }
}
```

See the Newtonsoft documentation [Validating JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/ValidatingJson.htm) to get more detailed information on how to validate JSON input.
But again, I recommend the `JsonSerializer` from the `System.Text.Json` namespace as it offers an async API.